# Problema al utilizar una función dentro de un ciclo while al imprimir los valores de un combo en PHP

Tags: php, select, combobox, function

Hola soy nuevo en esto de la programación en PHP y tengo un problema al llenar un select con valores desde una tabla de Mysql. Los valores del select son de la tabla escuelas de la base de datos EscuelaE y se tienen que ignorar todos los valores de esta tabla, que en la tabla usuarios de la base de datos UsuariosE tienen el valor en el campo activación de 1. Si pruebo el código sin la función que busca si se puede ejecutar el combobox, en cuanto le agrego el if y mando llamar a la función el combobox deja de funcionar.

```
<?PHP 

require 'funcs/conexion2.php';


function buscarCombo($numescuela)
    {
        echo $numescuela;
        $consultausuarioactivo=" SELECT activacion  FROM  usuarios WHERE escuela='$numescuela'";
        $usuarioactivo=mysqli_query($mysqli,$consultausuarioactivo)or die(mysql_error());
        $resultadousuariosactivo=mysqli_fetch_array($usuarioactivo);
        $res=$resultadousuariosactivo['activacion'];
        echo $res;
        return res;
    }



 /*DATOS PARA LLENAR EL COMBO*/
    $consultacombo =" SELECT  escuela,Nombre  FROM  escuelas  ORDER BY escuela asc ";
    $resultadocombo=mysqli_query($conexion2,$consultacombo);

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $numescuela = $_POST['numescuela']; 

        echo $numescuela;

    }

?>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>..:: Lista de Clientes ::..</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<body>

<div id="content">

<h1>Lista de Escuelas</h1>

<hr />

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" >
<table BORDER ="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tr>

  <td>ESCUELA</td>
  <td><select name="numescuela">
            <option  value=""  >ELIJA LA ESCUELA </option>
                    <?PHP
                        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultadocombo))
                        {
                            $parametro=$fila['escuela'];

                            if(buscarCombo($parametro)==0)
                            {   
                                echo "<option value='".$fila['escuela']."'> ".$fila['Nombre']."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
    </select>   </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="6" align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="Registrar Cliente" value="Registrar Cliente">
        </td>   
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: una pregunta entiendo que el número de escuela que existe en la tabla escuelas siempre existirá en la de usuarios, no? es decir esta consulta: "SELECT activacion  FROM  usuarios WHERE escuela='$numescuela'" siempre arrojará un resultado, siempre habrá un registro

Comment: Hola en la tabla de usuarios solo existen algunas escuelas que están relacionadas con un usuario, por eso se supone que busco $numescuela en el campo escuela, este campo tiene la clave de la escuela a la que está relacionado el usuario

Comment: Ahí estaría el problema dado que algunos valores no se encuentran de modo que en esas ocasiones no se arrojaría ningún registro, al no haber registro no se puede extraer nada de  $resultadousuariosactivo['activacion'], debes contabilizar las lineas que salen (creo que es mysqli_num_rows($resultado) ) si da 0 es que no hay ningún registro si hay alguno entonces sigues con el programa para ver si es 0 o 1 lo almacenado

Comment: Hola, la tabla de donde lleno el combobox es  la de escuelas y esta  cuenta con los 52 registros, la otra tabla donde  busco la clave de escuela en los usuarios en la función es la que solo tiene algunas escuelas, aplicaría lo mismo en cuanto a lo que tu me comentas??, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Dices que el problema es cuando usas `buscarCombo`. ¿Esa función arroja los datos correctos?, por ejemplo, cuando es `0` se imprime el cero cuando haces `echo $res;`? El campo `activacion`  ¿de qué tipo es `int, varchar...`? ¿`$numescuela` se pasa correctamente a la función?

Comment: Como te comento el problema es justamente ese que si escuelas tiene 52 registros y usuarios tiene muchos menos, es decir si buscar la escuela número 30 en usuarios y no esta. Esta línea $res=$resultadousuariosactivo['activacion']; no funciona porque no hay registro, por ello lo que te comento de contabilizar si hay o no registro antes de seguir con la extracción del valor del campo.

Comment: Hola si hay la posibilidad de que la clave de la escuela no  aparezca en usuarios, lo que pretendo hacer es buscar si la clave de la escuela existe en la tabla usuarios y pues no todas las escuelas están asignadas a un usuario, y pues si, tienes razón en que "$res=$resultadousuariosactivo['activacion']; no funciona porque no hay registro", entonces como hacerle para controlar esto, la idea es que si una escuela aparece en la tabla usuarios, esa escuela no la imprima en el combobox. En el combobox solo deben imprimirse las escuelas que no están asignadas a algún usuario. Gracias

Comment: Y el campo activación es de tipo int. y no funciona el echo $res; que tengo en la función, no se imprime nada, gracias.

Comment: No le está llegando un valor valido en el parametro $numescuela a la función function buscarCombo($numescuela), por que ahorita le puse un isset en un if al parametro y como no entra a al if se ejecuta normalmente el combo y la página y no me imprime el echo $parametro

Comment: Ya pude verificar que el valor si está llegando, ya que utilice un alert para imprimir el valor de las variables y agruegué mysqli_num_rows y la varialbe que toma el valor de esta función no tiene nada, la consulta me está fallando y la verdad no se por qué

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función quedaría así, pruebala y lo vemos:

```
function buscarCombo($numescuela)
    {
        echo $numescuela;
        $consultausuarioactivo=" SELECT activacion  FROM  usuarios WHERE escuela='$numescuela'";
        $usuarioactivo=mysqli_query($mysqli,$consultausuarioactivo);           
        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($usuarioactivo);            
        return $filas;
    }
```

Aparte de lo comentado de chequear si devuelve o no registro, también he visto que tenías un error en el return te dejas el símbolo de la variable $, no se si es un error de transcripción o también lo tienes mal en el programa.

Como mencionas que sólo tienes que comprobar si existe la escuela en usuarios, sólo compruebo las filas devueltas si tuvieras que comprobar y extraer el valor de campo tras el num_rows se expecificaría un if para ver si hay registro devuelto si lo hay entonces se seguiría con lo que tenías.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me funcionó muy bien, muchas gracias por tu apoyo y en si el de todos los  que trataron de ayudarme, saludos.

Comment: De nada Condor_G para eso es esta comunidad para ayudarnos entre nosotros cuando nos atascamos en algo.

Answer (score 0):

Primero valida que valores te trae $parametro=$fila['escuela'];

Segundo recuerda que en su if estas colocando que si buscarCombo($parametro)==0 
osea que la si la función buscarCombo es = 0, entonces va a mostrarte el combobox de lo contrario no mostrará nada.

Comment: Hola la mayor parte de los valores debieran ser 0, antes había hecho la misma función pero devolviendo un true si encontraba la activación en 1 y false si no.

Comment: Entonces valida lo que te trae $parametro=$fila['escuela']; y luego con ese valor realiza la consulta tu mismo en el sql para ver si te arroja los valores esperados que según te entiendo serían de 0. Verifica si le trae los registros y me dice como le fue.

Comment: Hola imprimí el valor de $parametro y cuando lo ejecuto me dá un 52 que es la clave del último registro, osea que si toma todos los valores y se queda al final con el último, también le agregue un if en cuanto llegara a cierto valor termitara el while y lo hace bien, solo me imprime la cantidad de elementos del combobox que le digo.     El archivo falla y no despliega el combobox si habilito la función que está en el código, si la deshabilito funciona bien el combobox. gracias

Comment: Seria bueno que muestres imágenes de tus tablas, 2 también muestra pantallazos de los registros que te trae las consultas. Así podríamos identificar más fácil el problema sin dar tantas vueltas.

Comment: Como puedo subir imágenes aquí, para subir las capturas de pantalla de las tablas??